# Use Service Principal in Azure CLI in VSTS Release Definition

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have a Resource Manager service principal configured through VSTS settings to access an Azure subscription. Everything works wonderfully when we use the Powershell Resource Manager built in tasks. However, we have a build agent that is running on a Mac because it needs to build a Xamarin project.

After Xamarin builds the .ipa we need to upload it to blob storage. We would like to grab the storage access token from Azure using the service principal on every release instead of storing the token ourselves, but we don't have access to Powershell because we're running on a Mac. We can use the Azure CLI, but we need to access the same service principal information that the built in Powershell Azure RM tasks use.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Powershell is now available on Mac](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell).

You may have to install the [preview versions of the AzureRM cmdlets](http://jessicadeen.com/tech/updated-powershell-core-and-azurerm-netcore-preview-module-install-scripts-for-ubuntu-and-os-x/) until the [real ones are released](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/2526).

Answer (score 1):

You can separate the build and upload action into build and release. In the build definition, run the Xamarin build and publish the .ipa file to artifacts with Mac agents, and then in the release definition, upload the artifacts to Azure Blob with Windows agent.

Comment: Yeah, that's an idea. Unfortunately we have more than a couple environments and doing that would effectively double the number of VSTS environments we need to set up and maintain: a build for each environment and a release for each environment. The tricky part is that unlike an ASP.NET site where we can switch out configs for each environment but use the same build artifacts, the IPAs have to be rebuilt with each config change AFAIK. If this is the only way we may have to pursue this, but it would be nice to have a way to use the service connection from the mac side.